# in multisheet excel generation using JXLS excel sum function not working properly

Tags: java, excel, jxls

I am creating an Excel workbook which has 2 worksheet; it has to calculate sum of a column in both worksheet, but it is calculating sum putting it on wrong worksheet (like calculating sum of first worksheet and putting that sum in second worksheet and and putting second worksheet sum in first worksheet)

```
Transformer transformer =TransformerFactory.createTransformer(is, os);
    XlsArea xlsArea=new XlsArea("Report!A1:N12",transformer);
    XlsArea entityArea= new XlsArea("Report!A1:N11",transformer);
    EachCommand entityEachCommand=new EachCommand("entity","entities",entityArea,new SimpleCellRefGenerator());
    XlsArea reportDataArea=new XlsArea("Report!A10:N10",transformer);
    EachCommand reportDataEachCommand=new EachCommand("data","entity.reportDatas",reportDataArea);
    xlsArea.addCommand(new AreaRef("Report!A1:N11"),entityEachCommand);
    entityArea.addCommand(new AreaRef("Report!A10:N10"),reportDataEachCommand);
    Context context=new Context();
    context.putVar("entities",reportData);
    xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Report!A1"),context);
    reportDataArea.processFormulas();
    transformer.write();
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to see the problem without having the template and the generated report. If you believe there is a bug you better create an issue in jxls issue tracker at bitbucket

Comment: i don't thing its a bug the problem is when ever i give a static file name to my  cell ref generator implementation  it works fine class JxlsCellRefGenerator implements CellRefGenerator {

        public CellRef generateCellRef(int index, Context context) {
            return new CellRef("Report"+(index)+ "!A1");
        }
    }

Comment: private class SimpleCellRefGenerator implements CellRefGenerator {

        public CellRef generateCellRef(int index, Context context) {
            return new CellRef(worksheetName.get(index)+ "!A1");
        }
    }   but this code doesn't work where worksheet name is a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

By default JXLS uses the FastFormulaProcessor, which is faster, but may lead to broken formulas in some cases. If you encounter problems, try switching to the StandardFormulaProcessor (see http://jxls.sourceforge.net/reference/formulas.html and https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues/44/multisheet-bug-in-sum-formulas-arbitrary):

```
        xlsArea.setFormulaProcessor(new StandardFormulaProcessor());
        xlsArea.processFormulas();
```